# How do I set the onCancelListener for a search?

Tags: android, search, listener, android-mapview

I'm implementing a `MapView` with a search feature, and have to perform some specific actions for the search to work well (I.E. turn on the layer of icons the search will query).  I'm currently using the `OnSearchRequested` method to perform these actions.  However, if the user cancels out of the search dialog, I want to return the map to its former state (that is, the state prior to pressing the search key).

I read in the documentation where it's possible to do this using an `OnCancelListener`, however I'm unsure how to add this to the search feature.  I understand that with a simple dialog you're creating you can just say `dialog.setOnCanelListenr(myListener)`.  However, since the search view is not being controlled by my `mapView`, how would I set this?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Apparently you should `OnDismissListener` instead of `OnCancelListener` because the latter is only invoked for specific events.</strike> [Using the Android Search Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle) explains this in detail and links to `setOnCancelListener` and friends.

**Note** - you only need a `Context` object to retrieve the `SearchManager` via [getSystemService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) and call `setOnCancelListener`:

```
SearchManager searches =
    (SearchManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searches.setOn{Cancel,Dismiss}Listener( ... );
```

Comment: The OnDismissListener fires whenever the search dialog closes - that is both when a user taps a search result and when the user cancels out of the dialog.  I have specific behavior I want to implement when a user cancels out of the dialog.  Furthermore, you can't just call the setOnClickListener(listener) method from a mapView activity, so I'm struggling on how to implement this function.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing that out about dismiss vs. cancel. I've updated the answer and added advice for setting the listener from within your MapView